# Activiti - exception when multi-instance service task itself inside a loop

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I have the below process. In that process there is a multi-instance service task (`Service Task 3`) that itself is a part of a loop.

[image: BPMN Diagram]

The issue is that I'm getting the below exception after the `MyProcess` is finished.

However if I make `Service Task 3` not multi-instance or if I make `Service Task 3` not part of the bigger loop, then I do NOT get the exception. So the exception is happening SPECIFICALLY for the case I mentioned.

```
org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.PvmException: already taking a transition
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:453) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:438) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:140) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:66) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.SequentialMultiInstanceBehavior.leave(SequentialMultiInstanceBehavior.java:75) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.execute(MultiInstanceActivityBehavior.java:98) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.SequentialMultiInstanceBehavior.execute(SequentialMultiInstanceBehavior.java:90) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97) ~[activiti-engine-5.22.0.jar:5.22.0]
```

The xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Service Task 1" activiti:delegateExpression="${serviceTask1}"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="servicetask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="servicetask2" name="Service Task 2" activiti:delegateExpression="${serviceTask2}"></serviceTask>
    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusivegateway1" name="Exclusive Gateway"></exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="exclusivegateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" name="list not empty" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="servicetask2">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[{!isEmpty}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="servicetask3" name="Service Task 3" activiti:delegateExpression="${serviceTask3}">
      <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="true" activiti:collection="myList" activiti:elementVariable="element"></multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
    </serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="servicetask2" targetRef="servicetask3"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow6" name="list empty" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="endevent1">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${myList.isEmpty()}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_myProcess">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="myProcess" id="BPMNPlane_myProcess">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent1" id="BPMNShape_startevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="180.0" y="250.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent1" id="BPMNShape_endevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="443.0" y="360.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask1" id="BPMNShape_servicetask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="280.0" y="240.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask2" id="BPMNShape_servicetask2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="576.0" y="240.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="exclusivegateway1" id="BPMNShape_exclusivegateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="440.0" y="247.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="servicetask3" id="BPMNShape_servicetask3">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="576.0" y="130.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="215.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="280.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="385.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="440.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow3" id="BPMNEdge_flow3">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="480.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="576.0" y="267.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds height="14.0" width="100.0" x="489.0" y="267.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow5" id="BPMNEdge_flow5">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="628.0" y="240.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="628.0" y="185.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow6" id="BPMNEdge_flow6">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="460.0" y="287.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="460.0" y="360.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <omgdc:Bounds height="14.0" width="100.0" x="470.0" y="309.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Activiti version is 5.22.0.

Anyone encountered this issue and can help?

Comment: Can you share your process in xml view? What version of activiti are you used?

Comment: I added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems to be a bug with an empty collection.

Quote from [Activiti Ticket tracker (Issue 748)](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/issues/748):

> I am facing a new issue with multi instance tasks which are failing with PvmException("already taking a transition") when the collection over which we are looping becomes empty at any point after looping.

You should try to create a new non-modifiable list before the loop. After checking that the original list not empty create a new list for looping.